# Undo NVIDIA driver change on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I recently updated my NVIDIA graphics card driver.  After install & reboot everything seems to load fine till login.  However, when I log in, the signal to my monitor is lost despite the computer tower remaining on.

When I attempt to switch to TTY3 at the login screen using Ctr+Alt+F3, the same thing happens.

When I attempt to use recovery mode from the GRUB menu I get hung on a flashing purple screen.

Are there any other things I can try in order to change my NVIDIA driver, despite the fact that my computer is in this troubled state?

Comment: If recovery mode does not work, Probably NVIDIA drivers have nothing to do with it. Did you do something else before this happened.

Comment: My system worked fine until I installed this driver.  I actually reinstalled Ubuntu from scratch and recreated the same problem by again installing the driver, to verify that the driver itself was causing the problems, thus I'm pretty sure the driver is at the core of my system dysfunction.  That said, I'll see if I can double check recovery mode itself before and after driver installation.